# Displaying text from file into a label or form background. Can't find answer to this

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to display text from a .txt file into a label or the form itself without having to press a button. I want it to display the entire file as default when it opens, instead of opening it through a button.

I am not using textbox because I do not want the user to be able to edit the text. Please help. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Write your code in Load event of the form

Comment: Double click on the upper border of your form, it will create a `Load` event handler, put your code in there. When the form loads, it will execute that code.

Comment: [`ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Label control and set the Label.Text in your page load method:
This should help:
Here's how you can use the Page_Load event, just put your code to load data in your `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10

MSDN suggests a label should be used if you want to show text on the page using the server code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, mate @codingyoshi! As I understand it, @kashif999 wants to know how to show the file without having to press a button and is concerned about using a label or the form itself - which is in the first line of the question.

Comment: Your answer will be a better answer if you concentrated on what the OP is asking: How to show content in a label without pressing any button. So yes you are right about the Load but your link points to a Label. That is not going to help the OP

Comment: Here you go @CodingYoshi. Thanks. I should have added that in the first place.